# How to Run Xcode Project From Terminal in iOS Device?

Tags: xcode, ios6, terminal

I want to Install Xcode Project in to iOS Device thru Terminal.I know how to Build Application using **xcodebuild clean install** this command.I want to launch app in device.Please can any body help me in this task?

I have tried some commands which executes successfully as well but now i am getting the following error when i tried to execute the following command.

xcodebuild -target "GoldenGate" -sdk "iOS 6.1" -configuration Release

export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

PROJECT="GoldenGate"
SIGNING_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: Deepak Shukla"
PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${WORKSPACE}/E6FD2816-7827-41AA-AC7E-2DC4833E637C.mobileprovision"

ARCHIVE="$(ls -dt ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/*/${PROJECT}*.xcarchive|head -1)"

IPA_DIR="${WORKSPACE}"
DSYM="${ARCHIVE}/dSYMs/${PROJECT}.app.dSYM"
APP="${ARCHIVE}/Products/Applications/${PROJECT}.app"

/bin/rm -f "${IPA_DIR}/${PROJECT}.ipa"

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication \
-o "${IPA_DIR}/${PROJECT}.ipa" \
-verbose "${APP}" \
-sign "${SIGNING_IDENTITY}" \
--embed "${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}"

#### Embedding '/E6FD2816-7827-41AA-AC7E-2DC4833E637C.mobileprovision'

- /bin/rm -rf /var/folders/wv/kv98qhfj6v36b2h0fkf_l66w0000gn/T/ouA93u702I/Payload/GoldenGate.app/embedded.mobileprovision
  Program /bin/rm returned 0 : []
- /bin/cp -rp /E6FD2816-7827-41AA-AC7E-2DC4833E637C.mobileprovision /var/folders/wv/kv98qhfj6v36b2h0fkf_l66w0000gn/T/ouA93u702I/Payload/GoldenGate.app/embedded.mobileprovision
  Program /bin/cp returned 1 : [cp: /E6FD2816-7827-41AA-AC7E-2DC4833E637C.mobileprovision: No such file or directory
  ]
  error: Unable to copy '/E6FD2816-7827-41AA-AC7E-2DC4833E637C.mobileprovision' to '/var/folders/wv/kv98qhfj6v36b2h0fkf_l66w0000gn/T/ouA93u702I/Payload/GoldenGate.app/embedded.mobileprovision'

Please help me in this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

# build.sh
#
# Created by iOSRider on 27/01/2014.

APPLICATION_NAME=MyApp

PROJDIR=/Users/iOSRider/Desktop/MyApp

PROJECT_NAME= MyApp

TARGET_SDK="iphoneos"

PROJECT_BUILDDIR="${PROJDIR}/build/Release-iphoneos"

TARGET_TEST_NAME="MyApp"

BUILD_HISTORY_DIR="/Users/iOSRider/Desktop/MyApp"

DEVELOPPER_NAME="iPhone Distribution: iOSRider India Limited (R8UAKS2M7L)"

PROVISONNING_PROFILE="/Users/iOSRider/Desktop/MyApp/iOS.mobileprovision"  
# compile project echo Building Project cd "${PROJDIR}" xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -sdk "${TARGET_SDK}" -configuration Release

#Check if build succeeded

if [ $? != 0 ] then   exit 1 fi

/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "${PROJECT_BUILDDIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" -o "${BUILD_HISTORY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.ipa" --sign "${DEVELOPPER_NAME}" --embed "${PROVISONNING_PROFILE}"
```

Comment: With This Script You can Generate the .ipa file and With The Help of Jenkins Connected iOS Devices Plugin you can install the app in to real device so you can take the advantages of CIS as well.